# How to use devise gem to be the Oauth Provider of another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, devise

Basically what I have now are 2 apps, 1 is php and the other one is rails. The rails app is the main app at the moment and contains all the user info, since I'm having a new php based app, I'd like to skip the whole registration and authentication part  on php and immediately have it authenticate on the rails app instead via devise.

Are there any good reading materials or anyone can guide me here on how to properly do this?